# Strip leading spaces only

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0

Given element:

```
 <comments>  comments
go here
</comments>
```

How can I strip what may be multiple leading space characters.  I cannot use normalize space because I need to retain newlines and such. XSLT 2.0 ok.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up.  I guess I should have read the instructions as I didn't notice it until my last post.

Comment: Good question (+1). See my answer for a XPath 1.0 one-liner solution. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `replace()` function:

```
replace($input,'^ +','')
```

That handles leading space characters only up to the first non-space.  If you want to remove all leading whitespace characters (i.e. space, nl, cr, tab) up to the first non-whitespace, use:

```
replace($input,'^\s+','')
```

Comment: How would you remove only trailing spaces?

Answer (score 4):

**In XPath 1.0 (means XSLT 1.0, too):**

```
substring($input, 
          string-length(
                        substring-before($input, 
                                         substring(translate($input, ' ', ''), 
                                                   1,
                                                   1)
                                         )
                       ) +1
          )
```

**Wrapped in an XSLT transformation**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output method="text"/>

 <xsl:variable name="input"
   select="string(/*/text())"/>

 <xsl:template match="/">
   '<xsl:value-of select=
   "substring($input,
              string-length(
                            substring-before($input,
                            substring(translate($input, ' ', ''),
                                      1,
                                      1)
                                             )
                            ) +1
              )
   "/>'
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when this transformation is applied on the following XML document**:

```
<t>    XXX   YYY Z</t>
```

**the correct, wanted result is produced**:

```
   'XXX   YYY Z'
```